# Application re-launches immediately after exit command

Tags: android, exit, launch

I am writing a simple application, and on the main menu, there is an "exit" button, which I want to exit the app. However, when I use any of the strategies I found online (finish, system.exit, UIHelper.killApp, etc.), the activity closes, but the whole app does nor close. Rather, the splash screen that appears for 5 seconds before going to the main menu re-appears.

The application will exit properly if it launches directly to the main menu, but I want to launch to the splash activity.

I appreciate any advice.

Comment: Your fundamental problem is trying to "exit" from an application.  Don't do that - it surprises the Android stack, which recreates the process.  The legitimate use cases for an "exit" are quite rare, outside of running certain tests on code under development.

Comment: Please don't put an "exit" button in your app.  It is anti-Android.  The only valid use I can think for it is to stop a background process.  If this is what you are trying to do, please edit your question to explain further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ChrisStratton and @Simon noted in the comments, providing an exit button is against the Android UI principles. However, imho here are cases an exit button is reasonable.

So first, Please make sure that you actually need an exit button, and leaving the activity is not sufficient feature-wise. If you only wish for an exit button for some workflows, make it customizeable (disabled by default). For a general overview on how Android apps should be designed, have a look at the [android design guides](https://developer.android.com/design/index.html).

---

For your actual issue, add `android:noHistory="true"` to your launcher activity declaration. That should prevent the user from getting back to the launcher. This will, however, not necessarily make the app behave like it is a closed desktop application, for example as your  app may have multiple entry points (intents, launcher, secret codes, notifications, etc.).

Comment: Appreciated. One of my team members insisted on it because we are targeting to old people who don't know how to use UIs anyway. So, I will forward this on.